# Alamofire not working while called from background fetch

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, background-fetch

I'm using background fetch in an iOS app to schedule some notifications and I need to fetch some data from server But when i create an Alamofire request the surver returns the data but alamofire does not calles my compilation handler (responseString)

the exact same code works perfectly while my app is on forground.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: method ?? HTTPMethod.get, parameters: parameters,
        encoding: encoding ?? URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseString{
        (afResponse : DataResponse<String>) -> Void in
    ....
}
```

I used [AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger](https://github.com/konkab/AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger) to check weather the response is created and fetched and the result was true. but my compilation handler not getting called!

any thing else should I consider while using Alamofire in background?

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested if it is working as suggested in [Alamofire network calls not being run in background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725511/alamofire-network-calls-not-being-run-in-background-thread)

We may have to start the call from background thread instead of the main thread (as it is the default behaviour).